# jQuery/JS/etc menu builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, mootools

I am trying to build an application. I want to allow users to create their own menu (with submenus also). I want to make this with JavaScript to be "live" (something like: to click add a button and then drag and drop to order etc).

**Do you think is there any jQuery/JavaScript/etc menu builder already for download?**

I have tried to search menu builder javascript/jquery but I only found online menu builders (not to download).

Any type of code is accepted (related to js) - `jquery`, `js`, `mootools` etc

**Thanks a lot!!!** *If the question isn't asked in the right place I will delete.*

**Edit**: I don't need custom styles like "select a design for menu". It only needs t generate `HTML` `<ul>` and `<li>`

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery UI alongside with jQuery (you must put jQuery UI script after jQuery and you must include a CSS theme e.g UI lightness). Start off with a `<ul>` and give it an ID (e.g `#menu`). Put all the base `<li`>s inside of it with the default values and the drag-and-drop `<ul>`s in a different element, e.g `#items`. Then in your script file, put:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu();
});
```

This will turn the ul into a menu. Now you want to make the items drag-and-droppable. In the same function, add this underneath `$( "menu" ).menu();`:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

This will let you sort the menu items. To let you move them from place to place, add this to your function underneath `...disableSelection();`:

```
$( "li" ).draggable();
$( "#menu li" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
            .appendTo( "#items" );
    }
});
$( "#items li" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
            .appendTo( "#menu" );
    }
});
```